# Amortizing in std::vector::resize and std::vector::push_back

Tags: c++, vector, resize, capacity

We know that the reallocation mechanism takes care of allocating more memory that we actually need when calling `std::vector::push_back()`.
Usually the capacity grows with the multiplier 2x or with a golden ratio number ~1.618...

Assume, we add elements as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    v.resize(v.size() + 1);
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the capacity of the vector is "doubled" if the reallocation takes place?
In other words: would the "+1 resize" allocate the memory the same way as it is done for `push_back`.

Or it is a pure implementation-depended thing?

Comment: I dont understand the question. You already mention that capacity usually grows by a factor of 2 (ie doubled) **or** golden ratio.

Comment: @tobi303 I think OP is asking about `resize` in comparison to `push_back`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew ah ok, now I do understand the question ;), though I still think it could be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the capacity of the vector is "doubled" if the reallocation takes place?

No. The complexity of memory reallocation is amortized constant.  Whether the capacity of the object is doubled when needed or increased by another factor is implementation dependent.

> would the "+1 resize" allocate the memory the same way as it is done for push_back

Yes.

`std::vector::resize(size_type sz)`  appends `sz - size()` value-initialized elements to the sequence when `sz` is greater than `size()`. That is equivalent to:

```
 insert(end(), sz-size(), <value initialized object>);
```

`std::vector::insert`, `std::vector::emplace`, and `std::vector::push_back` have the same complexity for memory allocation - amortized constant.

Comment: OP is asking about `resize`.

Comment: Since your "No" is only in response to the word "doubled", and not in response to what I think the OP's real question is (whether resize has the same amortized constant behavior as push_back), I would suggest, for clarification, moving your last sentence (where you explain that other factors than 2 are possible) up next to your first. Note that the word "doubled" is in quotes, and the OP already mentioned other possible factors, and used the word amortizing in his title.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, that definitely improves the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I did put the "double" word in quotation marks for a reason. And I explicitly asked about +1 resize. See the clarified question.

Comment: @paceholder, the answer is yes about the "+1 resize" question. I am not sure there is anything more I can add to my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> A vector is a sequence container that supports (amortized) constant
>   time insert and erase operations at the end; [vector.overview]

and

> If size() < sz , appends sz - size() default-inserted elements to the
>   sequence.

for resize. IMHO that means, yes, it is guaranteed that the capacity of the vector is "doubled" if the reallocation takes place